# ScrollViewProxy cannot work with swiftdata with delayed update

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

Suppose that I want to query a task list from swiftData and display them with textfield and an add button. I want to scroll to the newly added task in the bottom when I add one. Swiftdata just cannot work. I write a test code as follow:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TextView2: View {
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Task> { task in
        task.status == DoingTaskStatus
    }) var tasks: [Task]
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var ctx: ModelContext
    
    @State private var newTaskID: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                let task = Task(name: "newTask")
                ctx.insert(task)
                newTaskID = task.id
            } label: {
                Text("add")
            }
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(tasks) { task in
                            TestTaskList(task: task)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: newTaskID) {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(newTaskID!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TextView2()
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestTaskList: View {
    @Bindable var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("tap",text: $task.name)
    }
}
```

It just cannot work! I think the reason is that `ctx.insert` won't update the tasks array from @Query immediately. So that scrollto cannot find the target. So I tried the another way to prove it:

```swift
...
struct TextView2: View {
 ....
                .onChange(of: newTaskID) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
                        withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo(newTaskID!)
                        }
                    }
                }
...
```

Instead of scrolling immediately, I wrap it with a delay. This time it works. 
My problem is how can I deal with this kind of scroll with swiftData? I am sure by setting a delay is not a graceful way.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer, it works by using `LazyVStask` and `onReceive`.

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TextView2: View {
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Task> { task in
        task.status == DoingTaskStatus
    }) var tasks: [Task]
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var ctx: ModelContext
    
    @State private var newTaskID: UUID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                let task = Task(name: "newTask")
                ctx.insert(task)
                newTaskID = task.id
            } label: {
                Text("add")
            }
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(tasks) { task in
                            TestTaskList(task: task)
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(Just(tasks), perform: { _ in
                        guard let id = newTaskID else {
                            return
                        }
                        withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo(id)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back to a VStack and remove Combine if you substitute your .onReceive call with .task;
`.task(id: tasks) { ...`
You would also have problems if editing the tasks changes the sort order, and it might be better to create a boolean State variable that your set to true when a `proxy.scrollTo` is needed (e.g new Task created, or sort order of existing task changed) , and then set it to false after you have performed the scroll.  You would then change the `.task(id:` call to use your new State variable.